# Multiple annotations on related objects

Tags: python, django, django-orm

I'm trying to calculate some related objects for user using Django ORM.

As for example I have 3 models: `User`, `A`, `B`

```
class A(models.Model):
    creator = models.ForeignKey(
        'users.User', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='A_set'
    )


class B(models.Model):
    creator = models.ForeignKey(
        'users.User', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='B_set'
    )
    a_model = models.ForeignKey(
        'a.A', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='B_set'
    )
```

My query looks like:

```
User.objects.annotate(a_count=Count('a_set')).annotate(b_count=Count('b_set'))
```

When `b_count` always copying value `a_count` except when real number of `b` objects is 0. But when I'm splitting my query into two separate - it works good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `Count` with [`distinct=True`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/aggregation/#combining-multiple-aggregations) argument:

```
User.objects.annotate(a_count=Count('a_set', distinct=True), b_count=Count('b_set', distinct=True))
```

Comment: Could you explain please how it fixed my problem?

Comment: @Ernst Check provided link. Quote from docs: `Combining multiple aggregations with annotate() will yield the wrong results because joins are used instead of subqueries. For most aggregates, there is no way to avoid this problem, however, the Count aggregate has a distinct parameter that may help.` In other words since join performing on queryset both count will be the same, but distinct helps to fix it.

Comment: Thanks! Maybe it's better to use subqueries or I will not get perceptible boost of speed?

Comment: @Ernst Don't think it will give you any sufficient optimization, but it make your code more complex.